# total and subtotal in the teradata

Tags: join, count, case, teradata, subtotal

I want to get the following information **company's name, how many companies have status A and B and the total ( of all 4 status),**

but for total ( all 4 status) and subtotal (only A & B status) i get the same number - only the total one in both columns. Could you please help me out ?

the query in the Teradata is below ( table's and company's names are fake)

thanks

```
select  lpd.comp_name,
        count (*) as total, 
        count (case when ss.status in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) as sub_total

from lz.status_score as ss
join dm.lpd_company as lpd on lpd.id = ss.id

group by lpd.comp_name
order by
```

Comment: Either remove the `else 0` (to get NULL which is ignored when aggregating) or switch to `sum` instead of `count`

Comment: Or, if you're OCD like me and have to have an else clause, just do `else null` for counts.

Comment: thanks a lot you both !! your suggestions helped  :)